# drawing deep rnn

Tags: diagrams

Any ideas on how can I do something similiar to this (colors are not important):

[image]

Thanks !

Comment: Have you attempted to draw this yet? If so, please post your attempt. Do you care which package(s) to use to draw it?

Comment: I tried tikz, couldn't get furher than "regular" fully connected so far. I don't mind which package, do you think there is a better option ?